# If you don’t eat for a long time, you ........ hungry

Tags: conditionals

Which one is it?

1- would become
2- become
3- will become

I got this question in a homework and I didn’t know which one to choose, but I think the correct answer would be “will become”. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Either of the two options— 2 or 3— will work/work here.

Comment: Colloquially or informally, "... you get hungry" also works.

Comment: Think about this: How do you make a general statement in English? That would be 2). How can you refer to a future time as a general statement in English? That would be 3).

Answer (score 1):

Either 2 or 3 would be correct here.

However, there is a subtle difference in implication.

The first sentence is a simple statement of fact. If you do not eat, then you become hungry.

The second has a nuance of warning about it: the speaker is explaining the consequences of an unwise course of action. That is: "If you (in the near future) do not eat (your food), then you will (in due course, later today) become hungry."

Comment: There's not *always* a difference in meaning. #2 can ***only*** be an expression of a "general truth" (as "If you heat water to 100°C it boils"), and #3 can carry ***exactly the same meaning*** (as "If you heat water to 100°C it will boil"). The difference is that #3 can ***also*** carry the sense of a ***specific warning about the consequences of an actual or potentially ongoing activity***, whereas OP's version #2 ***can't*** really carry that "warning" sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... which is sort of what I said, in a more complicated way.

Comment: I can't see that. Sure, your answer says there are two different possible meanings, but I see nothing explicitly pointing out that ***one*** of those meanings can attach to ***both*** texts, whereas the ***other*** meaning can only attach to the ***second*** text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps I ought to have had "also" in the second one. But really, "nuance" implies "a little bit extra on top of what the main meaning is". If you don't like it, mark it down. Or go and write your own answer, or something.

Comment: It seems I'm wasting my time trying to be helpful, so let's just forget it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- would become
> 2- become
> 3- will become

Cambridge Dictionary defines 2) as Real conditionals and 3) as First conditional (likely to happen).

As the scenario is real, 2) is more appropriate.

Comment: 2 and 3 express slightly different things. 3 is more appropriate if that is what you want to express. Both sentences are correct, pick what’s right in your situation. Not a good homework question unless the homework question describes what should be expressed.